# IS NOT NULL vs = efficiency?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

in my Oracle DB `CLOSED_STATUS` is a Varchar2 column that is either `NULL` or '+', there are no other possible values besides those two.

I want to retrieve all the rows where CLOSED_STATUS = '+'.

Which of the following SQL queries is more efficient and/or faster?

```
SELECT ID FROM DB_ADM.ISSUE WHERE (CLOSED_STATUS = '+')
SELECT ID FROM DB_ADM.ISSUE WHERE (CLOSED_STATUS IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

My guess would be that there is no difference between the plans.  You'd need to generate the query plans for both statements to see if they are actually different.  If they are different, then we can look at why they are different and which plan is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if CLOSE_STATUS is indexed (and the data the table contains).

If not indexed, the execution plan on a trivial test table says the cost is the same.

But if the column is indexed, using `CLOSED_STATUS = '+'`  if more efficient than `CLOSED_STATUS IS NOT NULL`